Want to open locally saved pdf file in Chrome app programmatically
In my iOS app, I am creating and saving a PDF in document directory, and requirement is to open PDF in external Google Chrome app.
I am using below code to redirect to Chrome app.
//localPdfUrl = "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/44EF2F05-C4FE-4F86-AF0E-C7FE8B0EEA68/Documents/LabelsPdfFinalDoc.pdf" (changes every time)
@IBAction func btnOpenInChromeClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {


     if let pdfUrl = localPdfUrl {
         let chromeURL = "googlechrome://\(pdfUrl)"
         let url = URL(string: chromeURL!)
         if let url, UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
              UIApplication.shared.open(url)
         }
     }
}

but when I click on button, it redirects to Chrome but not able to access PDF file...
URL found on Chrome:
file///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/44EF2F05-C4FE-4F86-AF0E-C7FE8B0EEA68/Documents/LabelsPdfFinalDoc.pdf
It should be file:/// instead, and when I change it manually to "file:///" - instead of opening pdf, it searches keywords in search engine.

You don't use URL(string:) to access a local file.

If I use fileUrlWithPath - it looks like this "googlechrome:/file:/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F460B957-FCDC-48FF-8C19-78C052FD7C15/Documents/LabelsPdfFinalDoc.pdf"
and not even satisfying condition canOpenURL.
If I bypass this condition and directly use UIApplication.shared.open(url) - it does nothing.

I think files stored in the sandbox were not accessible from the outside.
You need to either upload the pdf file to the cloud get an accessible URL and redirect it, or display it in your app with the iOS PDF viewer UIDocumentInteractionController.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
